# Set-uid executable and resulting process user

Tags: debian, process, users, root, setuid

In Ubuntu 14.04, the `passwd` executable is

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 47032 gen 27 01:50 /usr/bin/passwd
```

and the `ping` executable is

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44168 mag  7  2014 /bin/ping
```

so (for both) the uid of the running process should result `root`, even when they are ran from a regular user. If I run `passwd` from `user1`, in fact, I obtain

```
$ ps -aux | grep passwd
root      4317  0.0  0.0  85940  2004 pts/0    S+   10:24   0:00 passwd
```

but if I run `ping` from `user1` it is not the same:

```
$ ps -aux | grep ping
user1    4362  0.0  0.0   6500   632 pts/0    S+   10:29   0:00 ping 192.168.8.1
```

Why the uid of the process has been set to `root` in the first case and not in the second one?

Answer (score 5):

As @schily says, in the ping utilility (and others), the root permissions are dropped after they are no longer necessary. This is done for security reasons.

From ping.c - main() - the user root is dropped with the getuid and setuid call.

getuid() gets the current user, and root doing a setuid() will change the uid of the process.

```
/*
 * Pull this stuff up front so we can drop root if desired.
 */
if (!(proto = getprotobyname("icmp"))) {
    (void)fprintf(stderr, "ping: unknown protocol icmp.\n");
    exit(2);
}
if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, proto->p_proto)) < 0) {
    if (errno==EPERM) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ping: ping must run as root\n");
    }
    else perror("ping: socket");
    exit(2);
}

#ifdef SAFE_TO_DROP_ROOT    
    setuid(getuid());       /* HERE RETURNING TO THE USER */
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

The general sense of @rui-f-ribeiro remark is correct, but the details are not. Details matter. Ubuntu uses these packages:

- [iputils-ping](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/net/iputils-ping)
- [passwd](http://passwd%20(1:4.2-3.1ubuntu5))

The ping utility resets permissions in a function named `limit_capabilities`, shared by ping and ping6.  The relevant chunk of code looks like this:

```
        if (prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS, 1) < 0) {
                perror("ping: prctl");
                exit(-1);
        }

        if (setuid(getuid()) < 0) {
                perror("setuid");
                exit(-1);
        }

        if (prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS, 0) < 0) {
                perror("ping: prctl");
                exit(-1);
        }

        cap_free(cap_p);
        cap_free(cap_cur_p);
#endif
        uid = getuid();
        euid = geteuid();
#ifndef CAPABILITIES
        if (seteuid(uid)) {
                perror("ping: setuid");
                exit(-1);
        }
#endif
```

That is (read the source code), `ping` performs several privileged operations and drops privileges — but it can be built to behave in different ways according to one's preference.

Interestingly, the changelog notes:

```
iputils (3:20121221-2) unstable; urgency=low

  * Enable the CAP_NET_RAW capability and strip the setuid bit on ping and
    ping6 binaries if possible.
```

The story for `passwd` is similar, with different details.  It is part of the *shadow* suite of tools, which may drop privileges in `change_root`:

```
    /* Drop privileges */
    if (   (setregid (getgid (), getgid ()) != 0)
        || (setreuid (getuid (), getuid ()) != 0)) {
            fprintf (stderr, _("%s: failed to drop privileges (%s)\n"),
                     Prog, strerror (errno));
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

But it only does this in a special case:

```
/*
 * process_root_flag - chroot if given the --root option
 *
 * This shall be called before accessing the passwd, group, shadow,
 * gshadow, useradd's default, login.defs files (non exhaustive list)
 * or authenticating the caller.
 *
 * The audit, syslog, or locale files shall be open before
 */
```

In the usual case, it ensures that it has privileges and does not drop them (because there is nothing else to do which doesn't require the privilege):

```
    if (setuid (0) != 0) {
            (void) fputs (_("Cannot change ID to root.\n"), stderr);
            SYSLOG ((LOG_ERR, "can't setuid(0)"));
            closelog ();
            exit (E_NOPERM);
    }
```

Most utilities do not reset the setuid/setgid behavior, presuming that they are not installed with those permissions.

Answer (score 4):

The uid of the second process has been reset already because there is no need to be root anymore after the sockets have been opened.

The `passwd` utility still needs root privileges when you checked.

If you like to verify this, you will need to check the source-code as the reset of the uid may be done too fast to give others a chance to verify the uid before the reset.

Comment: Right question, @heemayl. And here is another: who is devoted to reset the uid of `ping`? The kernel?

Comment: The utility itself does the reset.